# Webforms For Marketers - Has anyone successfully used a repeater in a custom built type

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm building a new control that acts as an inventory list for a user. The editor will choose the list of items to be displayed on the form, which I repeat over using a standard repeater. There is a textbox control that is added in the repeater where the user will add in the quantity of each item.

I'm a bit confused though on how to implement the validation for the control.

The control inherits from ValidateUserControl and IHasTitle. I've set the ValidatorContainer to the Panel control that wraps the repeater and the InnerValidatorControl to the repeater itself. However, this doesn't seem like the correct approach as for one, it doesn't work and throws an error stating the content may present a security risk and two, I don't want to validate the repeater, but rather validate the text in the generated textboxes to make sure the values are numeric only.

I've also tried inheriting from just the BaseUserControl and IHasTitle, however, the sitecore forms security risk validation is still run against the type and throws the same error as above.

Any ideas on how I could go about doing this? I feel like I'm possibly going about this the wrong way.

If I can provide any additional information to help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem I was having has been resolved. I realized that the ControlResult that I was creating, contained both '<' and '>', which, when looking into the Sitecore forms libraries, in the AssessSecurityRisk in Forms.Submit, are considered invalid characters.

So with that, I updated my control result string and it submits without error. Now I need to add some validation to the textboxes. We'll see how that works out.